# Regex to remove commas in the middle of sentence

Tags: php, regex

I wanna remove comma in the middle of text, I use this line of code:

```
$str = preg_replace('/ [,]/', '', $str);
```

it's ok for this sentence:

```
$str = ', this , is , my sentence';
```

the result is

```
, this is my sentence
```

but for this sentence:

```
$str = ', ,this , is , my sentence';
```

the result is:

```
,this is my sentence
```

The result that I want is

```
, this is my sentence
```

What is the regex that can solve that problem?

Comment: `/, /` instead? Note that `[]` is useless when you're searching for a single character. `[]` is used to represent many characters.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to just do it in 2 passes. First like you are doing (or since that pattern is exact text, a simple str_replace would be better) and a second pass to replace `,\s*` with `, `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this pattern `(?<!^),\s*`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qC7mJ7)